# Properly placing my raster over a shapefile on my map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, vector-grid, ascii

I have an ASCII file that I converted to a raster. My heading on the ASCII file is:

> NCOLS 156
>
> NROWS 720
>
> XLLCORNER -170989.3011812 m
>
> YLLCORNER 1417628.464462 m
>
> CELLSIZE 1
>
> 2 2 2 2 2 2 23 23 23 23 23 23 23

I want the raster to overlap a shapefile that have the above coordinates. The shapefile is a simple grid. For some reason, when I apply the raster to the map, it is located at the point 0,0 (Just off the coast of Africa.)

Has anyone ran into this problem before?

Comment: Have you checked that the coordinate systems are the same? Also, don't you need a Upper right coordinate as well as a Lower Left (LL)?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that when I add the raster to the map, it says unknown spatial reference. Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Hi @jcronin, if you converted the ascii to raster, then you should be able to [Define](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000) the coordinate system.

Comment: Check that if you add the raster by itself to a new map that you're seeing the correct coordinates from the header. After that, add the shapefile, does it overlay? If it does, the raster has the same coordinate system. If it doesn't, the raster doesn't have the same coordsys and you're going to have to either figure it out, or georeference it to the shapefile.

Comment: I'd remove ' m' from header. Also 'no data' line is missing http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm

Comment: AND what location does the shapefile and raster represent? aka where should they be located?

Answer (score 1):

You have a coordinate in your ascii for georeferencing but it does not tell anything about the coordinate reference system (CRS).
Use the "Define Projection" tool from the toolbox to add a spatial reference to your raster and your shapefile. (It looks like UTM?).

If they both are in the same reference system they will be displayed on top of each other.